# Selecting first 10 records, then next 10, paging using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How select first 10 records, Then the next 10, Then the next 10, and so long as the array will not end.

```
Phrases = bannersPhrases.Select(x=>x.Phrase).Take(10).ToArray()
```

How get the next 10 records?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
var total = bannersPhrases.Select(p => p.Phrase).Count();
var pageSize = 10; // set your page size, which is number of records per page

var page = 1; // set current page number, must be >= 1 (ideally this value will be passed to this logic/function from outside)

var skip = pageSize * (page-1);

var canPage = skip < total;

if (!canPage) // do what you wish if you can page no further
   return;

Phrases = bannersPhrases.Select(p => p.Phrase)
             .Skip(skip)
             .Take(pageSize)
             .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 Fairly certain this is the only answer that actually selects pages, the rest just select items 11-20 ;-)

Comment: If bannersPhrases is a `IQueryable` ignore the rest of the comment. Please don't do this at home ! `Enumerable.Skip` is O(n)! :-) (if you don't trust me, try looking at it through IlSpy/Reflector). I'll even note that you aren't caching bannersPhrases. I hope bannersPhrases is a fixed collection, because if it is too an `IEnumerable` then it will be regenerated for every page.

Comment: does it works with the interval? i.e. if I select the first record then I want to select every 10th record and then 10th and so on

Answer (score 23):

If you are doing paging and you just want to skip to a particular page you can use `Skip` and `Take` as described in some of the other answers. However, if you want group the entire sequence into chunks of a particular size you can use `GroupBy` instead. Here is a small example:

```
var groupSize = 4;
// The characters 'a' - 'z'.
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 26).Select(i => (Char) ('a' + i));
var groups = source
  .Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Index/groupSize, x => x.Item);
foreach (var group in groups)
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", group.Key, String.Join(", ", group));
```

The output is:

```
0: a, b, c, d
1: e, f, g, h
2: i, j, k, l
3: m, n, o, p
4: q, r, s, t
5: u, v, w, x
6: y, z
```

Comment: Could you please explain how your linq query works? I always thought you only had access to the collection element in a Select query. Over here you have access to the collection element plus an imaginary i, which I don't understand where it came from.

Comment: @ParthShah: It is not an "imaginary i". It is the index of the element in the source sequence. The overload I am using is [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).ASPX). I project the source sequence into a sequence that incorporates the index which I then use to group by.

Comment: Sorry for calling it imaginary. Wow that is such a cool query! You sir earned my vote!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.Skip()` .This will return the next 10 items:

```
 Phrases = bannersPhrases.Select(x=>x.Phrase).Skip(10).Take(10).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) extension method

```
Phrases = bannersPhrases.Select(x=>x.Phrase).Skip(10).Take(10).ToArray()
```