# Getting duplicate records while paging in list

Tags: c#, list, paging

I am looping on list which has 19 records. I want to get records in 4 pages. First page will have 5 records, second will have 5 , Third will have 5 and fourth will have 4 records.

So i am looping as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalColumnToShow; i++)
{

      var page = i + 1;
      var skip = rowsPerColumn[i] * (page - 1);
      PagedList =GroupedLinksCategory.Select(y => new copiedList { Title = y.Title, ID = y.ID, Name= y.Name }).Skip(skip).Take(rowsPerColumn[i]).ToList();

      foreach (var row in PagedList)
      {
         if (row.Name== "Test")
         {
            //my Logic
         }
         else
         {
             //my Logic
         }
      }

 }
```

variable rowsPerColumn is array holding 4 records like

`rowsPerColumn[0] = 5
rowsPerColumn[1]= 5
rowsPerColumn[2] = 5
rowsPerColumn[3]= 4`

On last page i am getting 2 records from page 3. What is wrong With my Logic?

Comment: How about you set some breakpoints and start debugging? If your last "rowsPerColumn" contains a lower value than the rest, this will ofset the last page... If it's `4`, then your `skip` will be `4 * 3` which is 12, so that will indeed show records from the previous page where the skip was `5 * 2`. Explain what this logic (`rowsPerColumn[i] * page`) is supposed to do, otherwise the answer will be _"skip a fixed number of records"_.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463734/split-a-list-into-smaller-lists-of-n-size

Comment: what is that count of GroupedLinksCategory?

Comment: @Anik1991 Count is 19

Comment: @CodeCaster rowsPerColumn is an array which holds 4 records as i shown in question.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. **Why** are you basing your paging on how many records you have in the **current row**? You cannot skip less records for the last row if the last row happens to contain less records. You need to skip just as much as before. You may want to skip the highest number in the array, or if it can differ per row, keep count of how many you already displayed.

Comment: @CodeCaster i followed this question to build Logic for paging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718117/selecting-first-10-records-then-next-10-paging-using-linq

Comment: @CodeCaster could you help me please on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last loop when i=3

skip is equal to 12 instead of 15. So thats why you get repeated value.

```
int Totalskip=0;
for (int i = 0; i < totalColumnToShow; i++)
{

  if(i>0){
  var skip = rowsPerColumn[i-1];
  Totalskip =Totalskip+ skip;
  }
  PagedList =GroupedLinksCategory.Select(y => new copiedList { Title = y.Title, ID = y.ID, Name= y.Name }).Skip(Totalskip).Take(rowsPerColumn[i]).ToList();

  foreach (var row in PagedList)
  {
     if (row.Name== "Test")
     {
        //my Logic
     }
     else
     {
         //my Logic
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: so what is solution for it?

Comment: Now first page is entirely skipped.. Why are we not using variable "page"

Comment: Now it skips last page